# android canvas rope swing

Tags: java, android, html-canvas

I'm creating the code, where a player swinging on a rope

for the moment I got this

```
double angle = Math.atan2(player_y - center_y, player_x - center_x) - Math.atan2(end_y - center_y, end_x - center_x);
if (direction == 'right') {
    player_x += 10;
    player_y += 10 * angle;
} else {
    player_x -= 10;
    player_y -= 10 * angle; 
}
```

I know that I have to add gravity, speed, etc... but I'm not very good in physics. The question is How do I make rope swinging more realistic?

I don't use any engines or frameworks, only native canvas.

**EDIT**

Tried this code.

```
onStart...
angle0 = Math.atan2(player_y - center_y, player_x - center_x) - Math.atan2(end_y - center_y, end_x - center_x);
length = Math.hypot(center_x - player_x, center_y - player_y);
swing_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
T = 2 * Math.PI * Math.sqrt(length / 9.8f);

onDraw...
elapsed_time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - swing_start) / 1000;

#with this player makes a very slow circle with the wrong pivot point
player_x += Math.sin((2 * Math.PI / T) * elapsed_time);
player_y += Math.cos((2 * Math.PI / T) * elapsed_time);

#with this it makes backwards circle    
double angle = angle0 * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI / T) * elapsed_time);
player_x += Math.sin(angle)
player_y += Math.cos(angle);
```

Where am I wrong?

onDraw called every 25ms

Log...
start - 15:31:22.411

```
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 1.1898202456306484
+15 the same
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 1.175053634797472
+18
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 1.13112033295045
+18
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 1.059110834176187
+17
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 0.9608125282061935
+17
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 0.9608125282061935
+17
﹕ T: 39.83959786319781 angle: 0.6957011399544965
+17
```

end - 15:31:29.361

Comment: angle is relative to elapsed_time not to 'deltatime' so try : player_x = Math.sin(angle);  (instead of +=)

Comment: tried player_x = Math.sin(angle); and player doesn't move at all

Comment: put some debug log. Ispect angle0, T, angle

Comment: log added, forgot about angle0, but it's around 1.1(to degrees(60-65)) and rope length is 400+

Comment: I don't remind all the trigonometry but I expect something like player_x = Math.sin(angle) * length; (keepeng the origin in 0,0) (sin and cos returns a -1..1 value)

Comment: player_x = center_x - length * Math.sin(angle) worked, thank for help )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pendulum physic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) to approximate your rope swing.

Calculate the fluctuation period (this is true for small fluctuations)

```
T = 2*PI*SQRT(L/g)
```

where:

```
PI = 3.14
```

`g = 9.8` (if I remember) the earth gravity acceleration 
`L` : the rope length, or better the length from rotation fulcrum to the character hands.

Then you get the fluctuation angle as function of time t as :

```
angle(t) = angle0 * COS((2*PI/T)*t)
```

where `angle0` is the starting amptitude

Comment: thank you very much, going to try it, but what small "t" is?

Comment: t is the time (in seconds) from the start of your simulation. Or from the start of rope swing